# Adding Node with CDATA to XML via PHP Issue

Tags: php, xml

I'm having an issue where when I store $msgIn (string) and it contains smybols like ampersand or currency values it will not save and cuts off from just before the symbol, is there a way to tell it to wrapp the message in CDATA tags?

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($this->currentChatLogFile);
$message = $xml->messages->addChild("message", $msgIn);
$message->addAttribute("timestamp", date("U"));
$message->addAttribute("pid", $uidIn);
$message->addAttribute("poster", $uname);
$message->addAttribute("ip", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$xml->saveXML($this->currentChatLogFile);
```

Currently getting this when i submit `Test & test2`:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chatlog created="1393450231">
<messages>
<message timestamp="1393453404" pid="16" poster="core" ip="127.0.0.1">Test </message>
</messages>
</chatlog>`
```

Any suggestions/help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    class ExSimpleXML extends SimpleXMLElement {
      public function addCData($cdata_text) {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($this); 
        $no   = $node->ownerDocument; 
        $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($cdata_text)); 
      } 
    }




    $xml = new ExSimpleXML('<root/>');
    $xml->item= NULL;
    $xml->item->addCData('CDATA TEST');
    $xml->saveXML("file.xml");

?>
```

example based on
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.addchild.php